# NestJS Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to create my custom `JwtModule`. I made `JwtModule` a dynamic module so that I can provide a private key using `dotenv`.

jwt.module.ts :

```js
import { DynamicModule, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CONFIG_OPTIONS } from './jwt.constants';
import { JwtModuleOptions } from './jwt.interfaces';
import { JwtService } from './jwt.service';

@Module({})
export class JwtModule {
  static forRoot(options: JwtModuleOptions): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: JwtModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: CONFIG_OPTIONS,
          useValue: options,
        },
        JwtService,
      ],
      exports: [JwtService],
    };
  }
}
```

jwt.service.ts :

```js
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CONFIG_OPTIONS } from './jwt.constants';
import { JwtModuleOptions } from './jwt.interfaces';

@Injectable()
export class JwtService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(CONFIG_OPTIONS) private readonly options: JwtModuleOptions,
  ) {}

  // I will do something here
}
```

users.module.ts :

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { JwtModule } from 'src/jwt/jwt.module';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';
import { UsersResolver } from './users.resolver';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]), JwtModule],
  providers: [UsersResolver, UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

users.service.ts :

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { InternalServerErrorOutput } from 'src/common/common.constants';
import { JwtService } from 'src/jwt/jwt.service';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import {
  CreateAccountInput,
  CreateAccountOutput,
} from './dtos/create-account.dto';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private readonly userRepository: Repository<User>,
    private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {}
  
  // I will do something here
}
```

I imported JwtModule into `app.module.ts` like this :

```js
JwtModule.forRoot({ privateKey: process.env.JWT_PRIVATE_KEY })
```

However, when I try to run this application, the console prints an error:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (UserRepository, ?).
Please make sure that the argument JwtService at index [1] is available in the UsersModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If JwtService is a provider, is it part of the current UsersModule?
- If JwtService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within UsersModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing JwtService */ ]
  })
```

Since I exported `JwtService` and imported `JwtModule` into `UsersModule`, so what the error suggests does not help. Using `@Global` to `JwtModule` is a simple solution, but as I will not use JwtModule elsewhere, so I would like to know the way without making it global. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic modules are just that, dynamic. They need to have their configuration/registration methods called when they are about to be made of use. You register the `JwtModule` in your `AppModule`, but not in your `UserModule`, so `UserModule` doesn't see the returned module with the `JwtService` exported, it sees a module with no providers and no exports. There's a couple of ways around this,

1. you can register the `JwtModule` in the `UserModule` directly, if you aren't going to re-use this, it might not be a bad idea
2. you can create a wrapper module tat imports the `JwtModule.forRoot()` and exports the `JwtModule`, then you import the wrapper module where you need the `JwtModule` and get back the configured module each time
3. this is mostly overkill, but cool to know, you can follow the RxJS Subject approach in [this repository](https://github.com/jmcdo29/dynamic-module-test) that would allow you to do something like `JwtMoule.externallyConfigured(0)` and get the configuration that was made in `AppModule`. Again, overkill, but cool